# AASM event and Rails model with the same name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aasm

How would I be able to use an event called `ship` in AASM if I also have a Rails model with that name?

```
event :ship do
   transitions :from => :quoted, :to => :shipped
end
```

```
class Ship < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Whenever I call the Rails method `.ship` AASM gets triggered and throws an error.

Is renaming my `Ship` model to `Vessel` the *only* way to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you show the model, containing AASM? It looks like it has ship association.

Comment: @TemaBolshakov: Yes, it does have a `ship` association!

Answer (score 0):

You should rename something: either event, or association:

```
belongs_to :vessel, class_name: “Ship”
```

Another alternative is to use [namespace](https://github.com/aasm/aasm/blob/master/README.md#handling-naming-conflicts-between-multiple-state-machines) for state machine events